# Can a subfile have its own preamble without the standalone package?

Tags: standalone, preamble, subfiles

Can a subfile have its own preamble without the `standalone` package? I tried adding a preamble to a subfile, basically just a different font and it did not work. Is there a way to do so (because I hear subfiles can have their own preambles) or is the `standalone` package the only way?

Comment: It would not be logical, because a preamble is a preamble, and when you put something in a subfile - meaning in the middle of the document - which has to be put in the preamble, you will get an error. But, depending on the document class and the packages you use it should be possible to start the subfile with a different font (already inserted in the main preamble) and at the end of the subfile return to the main font.

Comment: Yes, a subfile can have its own preamble (since version 2.0 of the `subfiles` package), but it will only take effect when typesetting the subfile. When typesetting the main file, the preambles of subfiles are ignored.